# Plotly plot doesn't show up when using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to plot a plotly heatmap with a slider. The slider shows up but the plotly heatmap does not. When not used with shiny the heatmap plots just fine. At one point I got the code to work but I have since broken it and I don't know how.

```
library(gplots)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)


#Ui
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("Example"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
sliderInput(inputId = "P4Volume",
              label = "Example:",
              min = 50000,
              max = 1200000,
              value = 30)
),
mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput(outputId = "heatmap"),
)
)
)

#Server
server <- function(input, output) {
output$heatmap <- renderPlotly({

*Code here that takes input$P4Volume and creates a matrix z

plot_ly(z,x,y,type= "heatmap",width=800,height=600)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've even tried a very simple example without the slider and just the plotly plot:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

x=seq(0,10,2)
y=seq(0,10,2)
z=matrix(100,nrow=6,ncol=6)
p=plot_ly(z=z, x = x, y =y,type="heatmap")

ui <- fluidPage(
plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
output$plot <- renderPlotly({p})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And I still don't get a plotly heatmap but when i plot it outside of shinny it plots fine...

Comment: Your minimal example works fine for me.

Comment: Hmmm. It generates a blank screen for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it works in chrome but doesn't work in IE. Changed my browser in R to chrome and everything looks good now!